# Another question on negative regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a python script that checks code for coding convention errors.  It does this by matching a regex that represents a violation of the coding standard.

One of our standards is that 'if', 'while' and 'do-while' conditionals must contain a conditional operator.

So no

```
if (var1)
{
    // blah
}
```

Instead I need

```
if (var1 == TRUE)
{
    // blah
}
```

For example, what I need for if statements is to match "if" at the beginning of the line, and find the situation when it doesn't contain "==", "<=", ">=", "||" or "&&" anywhere after it.  I've been pounding my head against the wall for a few hours and I'm hoping someone here can alleviate some of the pain!

Comment: I suggest you abandon the coding convention. Being forced to write `var1 == TRUE` is seriously lame.

Comment: You do realise that `if (var1 == True)` is regarded as unidiomatic, right? I realise you're using a TRUE constant, but then why not just use True? See: http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#testing-for-truth-values

Comment: **You do not parse programming languages with regexes.** It's simply impossible, and even if it was possible, it was a billion times too complex to actually do. Regexes can't even parse nested parens, let alone a complex grammar. You need to write a whole parser that gives you an AST that's queryable. Also, see the other two comments.

Comment: The coding convention is demanded by the FAA, so no getting around it.  I understand that regex limits much of what I would actually like to do.  But this is somewhat of a side project, so I'd assume not put the resources into writing a seperate parser.

Perhaps it was wishful thinking, but I was just attempting to find the most common violations

Comment: I wouldn't suggest writing a full parser on your own anyway. Which language is this? There is propably already a parsers you can use. In case it's C or C++, Clang might help (it's all C++ though, no Python). Or in case that's C++, [Vera++](http://www.inspirel.com/vera/) could make this much much easier.

Comment: delnan - thanks for the recommendations, I'll look into them.  It's all c++

Comment: @Vinay I think he intends to use Python code to verify the code convention for other code **written in some other language**. Apparently, one that uses braces for something other than declaring dict literals. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing, it works fairly well for the most part, not ideal though and we are looking into a third party parser.

```
^\s*\bif\s*\(\s*\w+\s*\)\s*$
```

Answer (score 1):

This could do it for the input you provided, but as mentioned in the comments, it's better  **using a parser** (e.g. [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/)).

```
>>> s
'if (var1)'
>>> s2
'if (var1 == TRUE)'
>>> if re.search(r"^if.+==|<=|>=|\|\||&&", s): print "found bad signs"
... 
>>> if re.search(r"^if.+==|<=|>=|\|\||&&", s2): print "found bad signs"
... 
found bad signs
```

Comment: You don't want to write a C++ parser. You really don't. There are barely one or two mature frontends that get it right (and a handful more that work with not-too-tricky code), and they all took way more effort to develop than any of use is willing to spend ;)

Comment: I'm not sure if we're talking about C++ here; but of course, you are right - reusing a parser already made by someone else is a much better solution. The whole point was that using a parser is better than using regexes in this case.